# how to refresh two functions without reloading the page in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to refresh the `blockrandompos` and `animblock` without refreshing the page

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var block  = document.getElementById("block");

function goleft(argument) {
  player.classList.add("animatel");
  setTimeout(function() {
    player.classList.remove("animatel");
  }, 1);
  console.log("left");
}

function goright(argument) {
  player.classList.add("animater");
  console.log("right");
}

function blockrandompos(argument) {
  var block3       = document.getElementById("block");
  var posleftblock = Math.floor(Math.random() * 370) + 1; //random numbers from 200 to 300 pos 
  var info         = block3.setAttribute("style", "width:30px; height:30px; position: relative; left:" + posleftblock + "px;"); //block settings 
  console.log(posleftblock);
}

function animblock(argument) {
  block.classList.add("animationblock");
  console.log(block.classList);
}

blockrandompos()
animblock()
```

Comment: What do you mean by refresh the blockrandompos and animblock?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why can't you call the functions on some event?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an event and subsequently an event-listener that can call a function when the event takes place. Beyond onLoad and onClick, there are a crazy amount of events that you can use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

So the question is, when do you want to run your functions exactly? Maybe we can help tell you which event to use.